# Model transformation with conversionMethod modern generates svf with different unit of measure compared to legacy method

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative

I have a IFC Solidworks 3D model with this type of measure unit:

```
#16 = IFCSIUNIT ( *,.LENGTHUNIT.,.MILLI., .METER. ) ;
#17 = IFCSIUNIT ( *,.AREAUNIT.,$, .SQUARE_METER. ) ;
#18 = IFCSIUNIT ( *,.VOLUMEUNIT.,$, .CUBIC_METER. ) ;
```

Using the legacy method the resulting SVF is correct (firse image) showing a millimeter unit.
Using the modern method (second image) the type of measure unit is forced to feet as you can see in the property panel.

The real value af the shown measure is 510 mm.
Do the modern conversion causing some issue?

[image: Legacy]
[image: Modern]

Answer (score 1):

The `modern` IFC conversion method is using the Revit-based IFC proccser, so the internal length units will be feet as expected. To make object properties be shown in meter, you can change it from the viewer settings panel.

[image]

If you want to change it by code, here is the code snippet:

```js
// Display units
viewer.prefs.set(Autodesk.Viewing.Private.Prefs.DISPLAY_UNITS, 'mm');

// Display Units Precision
viewer.prefs.set(Autodesk.Viewing.Private.Prefs.DISPLAY_UNITS_PRECISION, 4);

//Get human-readable unit names
Autodesk.Viewing.Private.displayUnits

//Get values for changing display units
Autodesk.Viewing.Private.displayUnitsEnum

//Get human-readable Display Units Precisions
Autodesk.Viewing.Private.displayUnitsPrecision

//Get values for changing Display Units Precisions
Autodesk.Viewing.Private.displayUnitsPrecisionEnum
```

You can also consider using Profile settings: https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/developers_guide/advanced_options/profiles/

```js
const customIfcProfileSettings = {
    settings: {
       displayUnits: 'mm',
       displayUnitsPrecision: 4
    }
};
const customIfcProfile = new Autodesk.Viewing.Profile(customIfcProfileSettings);
// Updates viewer settings encapsulated witihn a Profile.
// This method will also load and unload extensions referenced by the Profile.
viewer.setProfile(customIfcProfile);​
```

Comment: I don't understand why the Revit-based engine forces the display unit to feet ignoring what the IFC states and without converting all the values from the display unit of the IFC (millimeters as defined in the IFC at the 16th line) to feet. If I change the display unit manually or by code, when I use the measure extension I get the values converted in a wrong manner: the value 510mm is converted to 155448mm because the measure extension divides the initial value for 0.0032808 that is the conversion factor between feet and millimeters. This is not what I expect by the conversion of the IFC.

Comment: [Revit's internal length unit is feet](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/revit/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2014/ENU/Revit/files/GUID-099B3FD9-1C5B-459C-AC1E-EF958551DFB6-htm.html). When using the Revit-based engine, it will enforces all units to feet by the current design. Hope this is clear.

Comment: Regarding the wrong units conversion in the viewer, could you consider providing a non-confidential reproducible case demonstrating the issue to Forge Help `forge (dot) help (at) autodesk (dot) com`? A non-confidential reproducible case might contain model files, steps to reproduce, and a minimum runnable viewer code snippet.